# How to prove a submodular maximization problem is NP-hard

Tags: np-complete

We know that a submodular maximization problem of the form 
$$
\mathcal{P}: \,\, \mathop {\max }\limits_S f\left( S \right)
$$
where $f(S)$ is a submodular set function, is NP-hard (Claim 1).

This claim can be proven by reduction from a well-known NP-hard problem such as Minimum Vertex Cover (MVC) [1], i.e., showing that the objective function in MVC problem is submodular.

Can you please help me with the two questions below:

1. Does Claim 1 means that "every instance" of a submodular maximization problem is NP-hard? Or does it simply imply that the general class of submodular maximization is NP-hard?
2. Now that I have a specific instance of a submodular maximization problem
   $$
   \mathcal{P1}: \,\, \mathop {\max }\limits_S f_1\left( S \right)
   $$
   Can we (and how to) prove that $\mathcal{P1}$ is NP-hard?

[1] Rolnick, David, and Jonathan Weed. "Greedy Maximization of Submodular Functions." (2014).